# How I can get unread messages count for each conversation using an android twilio conversation SDK?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, twilio-conversations

Currently unread messages count is 0 and want to get unread messages count for each conversation.

I did used conversation.lastMessageReadIndex but it ask for return results to listener. Don’t know which listener we can use for that?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this...I don't know if twilio SDK provides a better way to do this...At least I didn't find it. I assume this is what you meant by "each conversation", my understanding it's that you want to find the total unread count of all of your conversations.

```
suspend fun getTotalUnreadMessageCount(list: List<Conversation>): Long {
    var totalCount = 0L
    for (conversation in list) {
        val count = conversation.getUnreadMessagesCount() //THIS MIGHT BE NULL
        if (count != null) {
            totalCount += count
        }
    }
    return totalCount
}
```

Suspend function because getUnreadMessageCount is also suspend, so you have to use this function in a coroutine.

It's just fetching unread count for each conversation and adding it to the total unread amount if it's not null. You can also do a ?: 0 to dismiss the if null check

Answer (score -1):

Try this code snippet

```
// Create a ConversationListener object
ConversationListener conversationListener = new ConversationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConversationUpdated(Conversation conversation, Conversation.UpdateReason updateReason) {
        // Get the unread message count for the conversation
        int unreadMessageCount = conversation.getLastMessageIndex() - conversation.getLastReadMessageIndex();
        Log.d("TAG", "Unread message count for conversation " + conversation.getSid() + ": " + unreadMessageCount);
    }
};

// Add the conversationListener to the ConversationsClient
conversationsClient.addConversationListener(conversationListener);
```